# Protege 3.2 RDF File

Tags: protege

I downloaded Protege 3.2 only to be able to run Sparql queries on RDF file now Protege 3.2 is not loading rdf file. When i try to open existing file, its says supported .pprj,.owl files but not rdf, any suggestion??

**my issue was that I downloaded Protege 3.2 just to run have a good IDE to run sparql but I'm not seeing the interface in it** 
[image]

Comment: I downloded protege 3.2, I'm trying to load rdf files but it can't, I'm also not seeing any place where SPARQL can be written

Comment: "Not seeing it" is not the same as trying. Did you try this instruction from the page you provided? "After launching Protégé, click on the OWL -> Open SPARQL Query panel... menu item. This will open a panel at the bottom of the screen."

Answer (score 0):

Protégé is an ontology editor in the first place. It works with Protégé project files and OWL ontology files.

If your RDF file contains an OWL ontology, you could change the file's extension to *.owl* and it will be visible in the *Open Project* dialog.

Comment: You're right, there are SPARQL possibilities. I removed "not a SPARQL interface" from the answer. I meant that SPARQL is not Protégé's main purpose.

Comment: Yes, my issue was that I downloaded Protege 3.2 just to run have a good IDE to run sparql but I'm not seeing the interface in it

Comment: I thought that your issue was that you couldn't open .rdf files?